# IF AND and IF OR in same formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

The calculation should be carried out when the following conditions are met:

- Lookups!B4=1
- AND Lookups!B5=FALSE
- AND Lookups!E8=2, OR Lookups!E8=3

The formula works when only one condition is set in Lookups!E8 as below:

```
=IF(AND(Lookups!B4=1,Lookups!B5=FALSE,Lookups!E8=2),100%-G50-G51,0)
```

But when I try to add the OR function I get a FALSE error:

```
=IF(AND(Lookups!B4=1,Lookups!B5=FALSE),IF(OR(Lookups!E8=2,Lookups!E8=3),100%-H50-H51,0))
```

I've tried nesting the OR bit too but cannot get that to work either.

Please can someone help....thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need second if. Nest `OR()` function inside `AND()` function. Try-

```
=IF(AND(Lookups!B4=1,Lookups!B5=FALSE,OR(Lookups!E8=2,Lookups!E8=3)),100%-H50-H51,0)
```

Comment: @Nene if you find it working then please mark the answer as accepted (tick mark it).